# Sharing App between two orgs

Tags: connected-apps, lightning-connect, survey, salesforce-survey

**Can we initiate a process in one org (org1), collect the data in a different org (Org2), and then pass the data from org2 to Org 1 ?**

**Background.**
Installed a paid third party tool to send survey in org1 (Sales Cloud). Instead of installing the same tool in org2 (Service Cloud), I want to share the tool between 2 orgs.

**Process:**

1. In org 2, from a lead record, Initiate the Survey by clickking 'Send Survey' button
2. Get the response for the survey in the Survey_Object__c in Org 1
3. Pass the responses for the survey back to Org2, and relate to the record from where the Survey was initiated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can obviously do it. If you want to be quick and dirty about it you can create 2 Sites with public Rest API and pass through those or you can create Authentification Providers with Named credentials, or create Connected Apps

Comment: Thankyou ! can you point me to reference documents or blogs to be able to understand the process.

Comment: sure, https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html - public Rest Site
https://www.sfdcstop.com/2020/04/connect-two-salesforce-orgs-using-named.html - secure version

Comment: As i think of this, I am wondering if a third party tool would allow the usage in a way i intend to. i.e Installing a third party paid app (and its managed packages)  in one org and accessing or using  this app from another org.

Comment: I was thinking so) You can do it, but you'll obviously encounter issues. On the second org, you don't have access to their SObjects (i.e. namespace__Survey__c), so you'll need to work with JSON or represent data in your own SObject.

Comment: from what I understand you want to have some sort of iframe on second org, so you can have UI experience  as if you were on org1, right?

Comment: if you actually want to replicate the experience of the Managed Package from another org it might be tricky. I think Canvas apps can be used to embed one org into another. One thing is moving data and another is showing UI from one org to another.

Comment: No, don't want to have UI experience as if you were on org1. We have two CustomerSupport teams - Sales(Org1), Service (Org2).  Both of these teams send out surveys after a call to a Contact.  Instead of installing a Survey App in both the orgs, I want to install the App in only org1, but this App can be invoked from org2. eg. Create a button on Contact record 'Send Survey' , which will send out a Survey from the app installed in Org1, the response received for org2 surveys will be posted to org2, and mapped to the Contact record, that way Org2 can create its own reports and dashboards.